# Blender mesh becomes messed up after importing

Tags: mesh, export, import

Alright, so I have this X wing model that was created in a separate game file, and I want to move it to a main game file with other models where I plan on making a game.  The thing is when I move it, it looks normal enough.  However, when I hit key "p" to play the game as a game render, everything on it looks messed up as far as placement goes.

So this is what it looks like after importing it into the game--as it should
[image]

But this happens after entering the game, pressing "p"

[image]

As you can tell, normal perspective is all messed up.

I am really confused as to what's going on and have played around with import settings, with no luck.  I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Can you make sure, that all your normals are pointing outward?

Comment: Yes, recalculating normals did nothing and flipping direction didn't change anything.  Worth a shot though.

Comment: @Leander I also tried separating all the loose parts of the model and after recalculating mesh separately, joined them again, and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It figured it out. It was all in the textures and I had to delete them all and then and add them back into the game.  When you import a obj into a game sometimes the textures and materials get messed up.  I just deleted all the material slots and recreated the material and uploaded the same image to be mapped on it.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit and then accept the answer by clicking the check mark on the left, so others having this issue have a fully fleshed out answer to follow.